# How to install scikit-image? (Windows - Python 3.4)

Tags: python, image, module, simplecv

I am working on a program that can identify objects, part of a much larger project for school. I have managed to convert these objects into white blobs on a black background, and need a way of detecting blobs (more than just one at a time) and storing a list of blob locations.

Originally I was going to try and write a function that would do this, but I realized that there are many modules that already can, and scikit-image appeared the best for it, and I did consider SimpleCV as well. However, I am having trouble installing either of them.

When I run the command

```
pip install scikit-image
```

It starts installing, but then I recieve an error:

```
    Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:
\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-6gpq3qdv\\scikit-image\\setup.
py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n'
, '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Tem
p\pip-3kmnznpy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --c
ompile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-buil
d-6gpq3qdv\scikit-image
```

I did try to install SimpleCV, however that requires OpenCV which is not compatible with Python 3.4 (I have to use 3.4 since it is part of a school project and my friends who are also working on it with 3.4 and it needs to be compatible)

Anybody know of why this is not working? If not, is there a library that can do the blob detection, installs correctly on Windows and is compatible with 3.4? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are on windows. The official site download page at http://scikit-image.org/download.html says:

> Windows binaries are kindly provided by Christoph Gohlke.

So, head over to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image

And get one of cp34 there.

OpenCV will not be available for python3 until OpenCV3 is released which will take some months.

Comment: I get the following error message when trying to install the file you specified: 'scikit_image-0.11.3-cp34-none-win_amd64'. Any idea why?

Comment: Is your python34 64 bit or 32 bit? Library also need to match the bit architecture.

Comment: I got this fixed now, turns out that I had to reinstall Python, appears there was something wrong with the installation.